# reflection GetBytes from int, int16, int64

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, int, short

how can i get the value of int, int16/short, int64 as byte[]

if data type is only known as object

I have some ideas like parse the Type-Name and foreach the int32-length-array

but i was wondering if there is a way with correct reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx)